# Calculating duration between two dates which go over months (splitting)

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, split, difference

I'm looking at calculating the difference between two date fields in SQL (SQL Server) which may (or may not) overlap to another month.

I have a TimeFrom field and a TimeTo field and a status field. Both of the Time fields are in datetime format and the status is numeric.

Here is an example of the dates:

```
TimeFrom               TimeTo                Status
2018-04-01 09:03:27    2018-07-15 10:11:13   12
```

I need to be calculate the time between those dates but in the relevant month and I'm struggling to work this out myself.

Output would look something like:

```
YearMonth | Status | Duration (hh:mm:ss)
2018-04 | 12      | xx:xx:xx
2018-05 | 12 | xx:xx:xx
2018-06 | 12 | xx:xx:xx
```

Comment: Could you also provide which db system you using.

Comment: We want sample table data and a matching expected result! (Still formatted text, not images.)

Comment: what about july time lapse??

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: you duration should be in days hours minutes and seconds in guess!!

Comment: The table has only 4 fields, 3 of which are listed above. There is only one more field which I've removed as it's not relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
set serveroutput on;
create or replace procedure d061(d1  in  date, d2  in date ) as
dd number;
hh24 number;
mi number;
ss number;
begin
select extract(day from intrvl) into  dd
    from (
          select   to_timestamp_tz (d1,'DD MON YYYY hh24:mi:ss')
                 - to_timestamp_tz (d2,'DD MON YYYY hh24:mi:ss') as intrvl
         from dual
         );


select  extract(hour from intrvl) into hh24
        from (
          select   to_timestamp_tz (d1,'DD MON YYYY hh24:mi:ss')
                 - to_timestamp_tz (d2,'DD MON YYYY hh24:mi:ss') as intrvl
         from dual
         );
select  extract(minute from intrvl) into mi

        from (
          select   to_timestamp_tz (d1,'DD MON YYYY hh24:mi:ss')
                 - to_timestamp_tz (d2,'DD MON YYYY hh24:mi:ss') as intrvl
         from dual
         );


select extract(second from intrvl) into ss from (
          select   to_timestamp_tz (d1,'DD MON YYYY hh24:mi:ss')
                 - to_timestamp_tz (d2,'DD MON YYYY hh24:mi:ss') as intrvl
         from dual
         );
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DD  HH24  MI SS');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(dd || '  '||hh24||'  ' ||mi||'  ' ||ss);
end;
/

declare
begin 
d061(sysdate+1,sysdate);
end;
/
```

output:

```
DD  HH24  MI SS
1  0  0  0
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: Apologies, I did forget to add that I was using SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

A proposed solution...

```
SET DATEFORMAT YMD
DECLARE @aux TABLE (TimeFrom datetime, TimeTo datetime, Status int)
DECLARE @res TABLE (YearMonth varchar(7), Status int, Sc int)

INSERT INTO @aux VALUES ('2018-04-01 09:03:27','2018-07-15 10:11:13',12)

DECLARE @secs int, @dt datetime, @fi datetime, @fo datetime,
        @f1 datetime, @f2 datetime, @st int

SELECT TOP 1 @fi = TimeFrom, @fo = TimeTo, @st = status FROM @aux

SELECT @dt = DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @fi), 0), @f1 = @fi
WHILE @dt < @fo
BEGIN
    SELECT @f2 = CASE 
            WHEN DATEADD(mm, 1, @dt) < @fo
                THEN DATEADD(mm, 1, @dt)
                ELSE DATEADD(ss, 1, @fo)
            END
    SELECT @secs = DATEDIFF(ss, @f1, DATEADD(s, - 1, @f2))
    INSERT INTO @res VALUES (CONVERT(varchar(7), @dt, 120), @st, @secs)
    SELECT @f1 = @f2, @dt = DATEADD(mm, 1, @dt)
END

SELECT YearMonth,status
    ,CAST(Sc / 3600 AS varchar) + '.'
    +RIGHT('0' + CAST((Sc - 3600 * (Sc / 3600)) / 60 AS varchar(2)), 2) + '.'
    +RIGHT('0' + CAST(Sc % 60 AS varchar(2)), 2) AS [Duration (hhh.mm.ss)]
FROM @res
```